# Converting all elements of a nested list of strings (wich contains another nested list) to a nested list of integers

Tags: python, arrays, nested

I have a function that opens a text file and return me a *x* nested list of strings, I want to convert all elements to integers, but inside *x* there is another nested list:

This is `x`:

```
[
    ['7', '1'], 
    ['1', '6', '4', '1'], 
    ['2', '1', '0', '0'], 
    [
        ['1', '0', '4', '5'], 
        ['9', '3', '0', '7'], 
        ['0', '1', '2', '0']
    ], 
    [
        ['8', '0', '2', '6'], 
        ['6', '3', '8', '8'], 
        ['3', '0', '0', '1']
    ]
]
```

I've tried to use the `map` function:

```
for elems in x:
    converted = list(map(int, n) for n in elems)
```

Output:

```
[<map object at 0x000002466CC00D60>, <map object at 0x000002466CC010F0>, <map object at 0x000002466CC01180>]
```

Also tried:

```
for elems in x:
    converted = list(map(int, elems))
```

Which gave me this error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'list'
```

Expected output:

```
[
    [7, 1], 
    [1, 6, 4, 1], 
    [2, 1, 0, 0], 
    [
        [1, 0, 4, 5], 
        [9, 3, 0, 7], 
        [0, 1, 2, 0]
    ], 
    [
        [8, 0, 2, 6], 
        [6, 3, 8, 8], 
        [3, 0, 0, 1]
    ]
]
```

How can I do this conversion? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf question updated with the expected output

Comment: I added an answer.

Comment: When the data can be nested arbitrarily, the first thing that should come to mind is "recursion".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can apply the map function to a list of strings, but not to a list of lists. You can, however, do this by recursion:

```
l = [['7', '1'], ['1', '6', '4', '1'], ['2', '1', '0', '0'], 
    [['1', '0', '4', '5'], ['9', '3', '0', '7'], ['0', '1', '2', '0']], 
    [['8', '0', '2', '6'], ['6', '3', '8', '8'], ['3', '0', '0', '1']]]

def f(l):
    if type(l[0]) == str:
        return list(map(int, l))
    return [f(i) for i in l]

f(l)
```

output:

```
[[7, 1], [1, 6, 4, 1], [2, 1, 0, 0], [[1, 0, 4, 5], [9, 3, 0, 7], [0, 1, 2, 0]], [[8, 0, 2, 6], [6, 3, 8, 8], [3, 0, 0, 1]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function:

```py
def convert(x):
    result = []
    if type(x) == str:
        return int(x)

    if type(x) == list:
        for e in x:
            result.append(convert(e))

    return result
```

When calling

```
x = [
    ['7', '1'],
    ['1', '6', '4', '1'],
    ['2', '1', '0', '0'], 
    [
        ['1', '0', '4', '5'], ['9', '3', '0', '7'], ['0', '1', '2', '0']
    ], 
    [
        ['8', '0', '2', '6'], ['6', '3', '8', '8'], ['3', '0', '0', '1']
    ],
]
convert(x)
```

**Output:**

```
[[7, 1], [1, 6, 4, 1], [2, 1, 0, 0], [[1, 0, 4, 5], [9, 3, 0, 7], [0, 1, 2, 0]], [[8, 0, 2, 6], [6, 3, 8, 8], [3, 0, 0, 1]]]
```

**Explanation**

Notice that it will convert an element to an `int` only when the element is a `str`. When the element is a `list`, it will make a recursive call.